# Randomizing pages within a block in Qualtrics?

Tags: random, qualtrics

In Qualtrics, is it possible to randomize the pages within a block?  So for example, take this Block 1:

```
------Page Break------
1. Do you like cats?
2. Do you like dogs? 
------Page Break------
3. Do you like parrots?
4. Do you like apples?
5. Do you like bananas?
------Page Break------
6. Do you like pizza?
7. Do you like fish?
------Page Break------
```

Is it possible randomize the order that each page appears (e.g., Q3,4,5 might appear first, Q1&2 second, and Q6&7 third).

I have a ton of survey pages, and it would be pretty painful to have to break them all up into many different blocks just to randomize them.  (However, if there's an easy way to do that, I'd love to hear.)

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Even more complicated, what I also need to do is group pages together and then randomize based on groups of pages (e.g., Qs1-5 might be a group of pages, and would "travel" together during randomization).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible, but you can shift click on the first and last question per page, click move and move all into a new block fairly quickly. That is the fastest way that I know of.

Comment: Okay, I was afraid of that! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a problem. I've typically found i can break up about 10 to 20 pages per minute doing it this way, so hopefully it doesnt take too long!